# Twin query on Azure sample code is redundant query.nextAsTwin(onResults)?

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-iot-hub

I am trying to query Twin information from Azure IoT hub using sample code as below. But I not sure why we need query.nextAsTwin(onResults) 2 times. Any impact if I remove the 2sd one?

reference: https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node/blob/main/service/samples/javascript/twin_query.js

```
var Registry = require('azure-iothub').Registry;

var connectionString = process.env.IOTHUB_CONNECTION_STRING;
var registry = Registry.fromConnectionString(connectionString);

var query = registry.createQuery('SELECT * FROM devices', 100);
var onResults = function(err, results) {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Failed to fetch the results: ' + err.message);
  } else {
    // Do something with the results
    results.forEach(function(twin) {
      console.log(twin.deviceId);
    });

    if (query.hasMoreResults) {
        query.nextAsTwin(onResults);
    }
  }
};

query.nextAsTwin(onResults);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [IoT Hub query language for device and module twins, jobs, and message routing](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-query-language.md#nodejs-example):

> The query object is instantiated with a page size (up to 100). Then multiple pages are retrieved by calling the `nextAsTwin` method multiple times.

If you have more than 100 page size then you can call `nextAsTwin` twice, otherwise you can remove the redundancy.

You can refer to other example: [Get started with device twins (Node.js)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-node-node-twin-getstarted#:%7E:text=When%20the%20code,of%20aggregation%20queries.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your easy explanation.

Answer (score 0):

In the code, you posted, `onResults` is a function that prints out the device ID for every twin returned in the query result. If the query indicates more results, it calls `query.nextAsTwin(onResults);` again. This is not redundant; it's a recursive function that will keep calling itself until there are no more results in the query.

In your example, the query will return 100 results at a time, as specified in the pageSize parameter in your code:

```js
registry.createQuery('SELECT * FROM devices', 100);
```

So multiple calls to `nextAsTwin` will be necessary when there are more than 100 results.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is similar to the first comment so I marked the first one is answered.